# one click animations with lua in LOVE

Tags: animation, lua, love2d

I have recently been familiar with lua in LOVE 2D and watched some tutorials and now am trying to make a simple game. The game will feature a character who can run and when pressed 'space', attack(strike with his sword). When pressed 'space', it should go through all the frames/sprites of attacking animation. But the character is not going through all the frames and the interval between them seems really fast even though I kept it minimum.

This is the code I am using to account for the key pressing.

```
self.animations = {
        ['idle'] = Animation{
            frames = {
                self.frames[1]
            },
            interval = 1
        },
        ['attack'] = Animation{
            frames = {
                self.frames[1], self.frames[2], self.frames[3], self.frames[4], self.frames[5], self.frames[6], self.frames[3]
            },
            interval = 0.25
        }
    }

    self.animation = self.animations['idle']
    self.currentFrame = self.animation:getCurrentFrame()

    self.behaviors = {
        ['idle'] = function(dt)

            if love.keyboard.wasPressed('space') then
                self.dy = 0
                self.state = 'attack'
                self.animation = self.animations['attack']
            elseif love.keyboard.wasPressed('up') then
                self.dy = -MOVE_DIST
            elseif love.keyboard.wasPressed('down') then
                self.dy = MOVE_DIST
            else
                self.dy = 0
            end
        end,
        ['attack'] = function(dt)
            self.animation = self.animations['attack']
            if love.keyboard.wasPressed('up') then
                self.dy = -MOVE_DIST
            elseif love.keyboard.wasPressed('down') then
                self.dy = MOVE_DIST
            else
                self.dy = 0
                self.state = 'idle'
                self.animation = self.animations['idle']
            end
        end
```

This is my animation class that's responsible for transition effects

```
Animation = Class{}

function Animation:init(params)
    --self.texture = params.texture
    self.frames = params.frames
    self.interval = params.interval or 0.05
    self.timer = 0
    self.currentFrame = 1


end

function Animation:getCurrentFrame()
    return self.frames[self.currentFrame]
end

function Animation:restart()
    self.timer = 0
    self.currentFrame = 1
end

function Animation:update(dt)
    self.timer = self.timer + dt

    if #self.frames == 1 then
        return self.currentFrame

    else
        while self.timer > self.interval do
            self.timer = self.timer - self.interval

            self.currentFrame = (self.currentFrame + 1) % (#self.frames + 1)

            if self.currentFrame == 0 then
                self.currentFrame = 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Please help. I hope I asked the question correctly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know how you deal with the state in the key pressing code but this could be part of the issue too.
Anyway, your Animation:update looks very weird to me and I really think this is the center of the problem. There is a simple function that you could use instead and it should work perfectly (if you have any question about it feel free to ask).
If your not really comfortable with a debugger you could use [love.graphics.print](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.print) to print some value to the screen (like self.currentFrame or self.timer in that case) to see what's going on with those value in real time.

```lua
function Animation:update(dt)
    self.timer = self.timer + dt/self.interval

    if self.timer >= #self.frames then
        self.timer = 0
    end

    self.currentFrame = Math.floor(self.timer)+1
end
```

Also note that "Math.floor(self.timer)+1" cannot be replaced by "Math.ceil(self.timer)" because it will return 0 if self.timer == 0 (and lua's array starts at one)

Edit:
It could probably come from here:

```lua
['attack'] = function(dt)
    self.animation = self.animations['attack']
    if love.keyboard.wasPressed('up') then
        self.dy = -MOVE_DIST
    elseif love.keyboard.wasPressed('down') then
        self.dy = MOVE_DIST
    else
        self.dy = 0
        self.state = 'idle'
        self.animation = self.animations['idle']
    end
end
```

I don't know how you deal with your inputs since 'love.keyboard.wasPressed' if not a love function but if 'up' and 'down' where not pressed the last frame, the state will go back to 'idle' and the animation to animations['idle']

Without more code I cannot do much more for you.

Comment: DeramMath Your Animation: update is cleaner and thank you for that. But it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @prbiswas I edited my answer a while ago, but apparently my comment to notify you didn't get posted. Hope the edit helped you or that you found a solution since.